# Não estou conseguindo criar a relação entre as tabelas através das migrações do Laravel

Tags: laravel, migrations

Estou utilizando o Multi Tenancy no Laravel, então criei as migrations, sem relacionamento entre tabela estava funcionando normal, quando relacionei que começou o erro.

Pensei que era a ordem de execução das migrações, então renomeei para executar na forma que correta, mas o erro continuou.

migrations -> 2019_08_07_024917_lista

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tbd_lista', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nome')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

migrations -> 2019_08_08_024935_cartao

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tbd_cartao', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nome',100)->nullable();
            $table->integer('tbd_lista_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('tbd_lista_id')->references('id')->on('tbd_lista');
            $table->longText('descricao');
            $table->boolean('arquivar');    
            $table->dateTime('data');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Erro:

"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `tbd_cartao` add constraint `tbd_cartao_tbd_lista_id_foreign` foreign key (`tbd_lista_id`) references `tbd_lista` (`id`))"

Comment: To estudando laravel também :v cabei de passar por algo parecido. Seguinte tenta troca $table->integer('tbd_lista_id')->unsigned(); por $table->bigInteger('tbd_lista_id')->unsigned();. talvez vc precise apagar essa tabela do banco na mão.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você ta usando bigIncrements você precisa passar na outra tabela bigInteger segue seu próprio código alterado:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tbd_cartao', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nome',100)->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('tbd_lista_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('tbd_lista_id')->references('id')->on('tbd_lista');
            $table->longText('descricao');
            $table->boolean('arquivar');    
            $table->dateTime('data');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Deixe para fazer a relação entre as tabelas em seus models, no desenvolvimento, no código, e não no banco de dados. Se o problema for por causa de deleção use $table->softDeletes() e não delete nda.

Isso ajuda na auditoria posterior, estatísticas e até na recuperação da informação.

Dê uma olhada nestes artigos:

https://medium.com/@hernandev/sempre-use-chaves-estrangeiras-no-mysql-e24b4e2187f5

https://medium.com/@lemesdaniel/o-porqu%C3%AA-de-eu-n%C3%A3o-usar-chave-estrangeira-no-mysql-2e0179af4b2c

Answer (score 0):

trocar **$table->integer('tbd_lista_id')->unsigned();**
 por **$table->bigInteger('tbd_lista_id')->unsigned();**
 para ficar identico a primary key da tabela relacionada.

Answer (score -1):

Eu já passei várias vezes por isso e minha solução foi fazer um backup das tabelas deletar o banco e rodar o php artisan migration novamente, por que por algum motivo o laravel não aceita novas tabelas com foreign key.

Comment: Ele aceita, mas ele espera uma coisa mais inteligente, tentar por bigInteger em integer impossível.